# Content deployment deploys everything except document library contents (PDF's, excel docs) - Log included

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

**Background of problem**

We are developing an extranet.  It's primary purpose is to share pdf's and xls files with external customers.  After content deployment, everything works as expected, except the pdf's and xls documents fail to import. I will respond as quickly as possible to any additional requests for background on the behavior.

**Topology**

We have an internal authoring environment and an external content deployment target outside the firewall. We set up content deployment between the two environments.  The source site is based upon the team site site collection template.

**Due Diligence**

1. I have confirmed that both the source and the target are at the same patch level for SharePoint and SQL 2008
2. The target site was created leaving the site collection as "Choose template later"
3. Our 2 custom solutions that provision the lists and styling were deployed to the target, but their features were not activated.
4. The lists do *not* require content approval.

**What works**

When we run content deployment, the following work as expected:

1. Custom features are activated
2. Master pages, images, css are deployed
3. Custom lists are created.

**Issue**

Everything behaves as expected, except none of the "meat" of the site (the actual document library items) is created.

**Log**

Below is the log section for both a master page and an example pdf.  Note that they are nearly exactly the same (Names changed to protect the innocent).

```
Good:
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [Foo.Default.Master] Progress: Importing
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [Foo.Default.Master]   Verbose: List URL: /_catalogs/masterpage
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [Foo.Default.Master]   Progress: Importing Links
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [Foo.Default.Master]     Verbose: Import 1 server-relative links.

Bad
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [ExampleDocument.pdf] Progress: Importing
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [ExampleDocument.pdf]   Verbose: List URL: /Customer Reports
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [ExampleDocument.pdf]   Progress: Importing Links
[3/2/2011 9:24:08 AM] [ListItem] [ExampleDocument.pdf]     Verbose: Import 1 server-relative links.
```

We also received ~100 of these exceptions on the first run of content deployment, but the amount of errors do not correspond to the number of imported documents (~5000).  Googling around a bit hints that this might not be the reason for our problems, but I'm putting it out there in case I'm wrong.

```
[3/2/2011 9:26:01 AM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportObjectManager.FixBrokenMvlInListItem(ListItemMvl brokenField)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ImportObjectManager.FixBrokenLookup(DeploymentLookupField brokenField)
```

...Peter

Comment: Have you looked at: [Content Deployment Best Practices](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/01/16/content-deployment-best-practices.aspx). It's for SP2007 but presumably most will apply.

Comment: I did look at that article.  Nothing jumped out at me specifically. I tried to cover my bases on that article by putting the due diligence section in.  I suspect one of my custom columns isn't configured properly.  I'm going to create some test lists piecemeal slowly add the columns to see which column is giving us trouble.

Comment: Are you saying that the "Bad" log example you posted was simply not put into the library? 

Is it possible to provide the entire log?

Comment: Have you verified that the server allows adequate permissions for the location that you are importing the files to?

Comment: I sadly can't post more of the log... I can't show the info from the client.

Comment: I am confident that the perms are ok, otherwise the master page wouldn't have come across.